# PHP Function Running Before Redirect

Tags: php, mysql

At the top of a php script I've got a method that checks a users credentials and if their SESSION variables don't match what we expect they are redirected via header("Location: ..") to the login area.

Below this I've got a method that detects query string parameters and then runs a mysql command accordingly:

// INSIDE GATEKEEPER

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['ourprivatesessionvar'])) { header("Location: login.php");
```

// INSIDE MY SCRIPT

```
include('includes/gatekeeper.php');

/** SOME OTHER STUFF **/

if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
     mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['delete'])."' LIMIT 1"); 
}
```

So to sum it up - the delete command is running regardless of whether or not the session quota is met.

Comment: Where is the `quota` checked? Looks like you are only checking if the delete is set. If the `sessionvar` is being met you should add an `exit` after the `header`.

Comment: Add exit() or die() after the header.

Comment: You always need to exit after a `header(`Location: xxx')` as it does not terminate the code and therefore continues to process the rest of the script.

Comment: write exit after header("Location: login.php");

Answer (score 3):

Terminate the script using `exit;` or `die;` after redirect.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['ourprivatesessionvar'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've never had this problem before and have been using this method for a long time.  Is there a specific configuration setting that would cause the script to continue running without "exit;"?

Comment: No. PHP's header function just sends the browser a HTTP header to tell the browser what to do, it doesn't stop the script executing at all (in case e.g. you wanted to log the redirect, clean up a session, delete temp files etc.) - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['ourprivatesessionvar'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    die;
}
```

or

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['ourprivatesessionvar'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    return false;
}
```

or

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['ourprivatesessionvar'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
```